# Mapbox android load Time based tiles

Tags: xamarin, mapbox-android

I have a time based tile server with radar data. I want to show this in mapbox.

The only way I get this working is this. Remove Source and layer and create a new source and layer.

```
 mapboxMap.RemoveLayer("layer");
 mapboxMap.RemoveSource("source");
 RasterSource source = new RasterSource("source", tileset, 256);

 mapboxMap.AddSource(source);
 RasterLayer layer = new RasterLayer("layer", "source");
 mapboxMap.AddLayer(layer);
```

This is working, bur the problem is that it is flickering. Is there another way to do this. I'm using Naxam.Mapbox.Droid version for Xamarin.

Thanks 
Jelle

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve here? You need to refresh this time and time again?

Comment: I want to show rain radar tiles, it is showing only it the animation is not smooth. That is I think that I remove the layer and source. But cannot find another way to do this.

Comment: There should a method to refresh these layers right?